# What's the difference between Bootstrap Spans & Columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, html

I working with bootstrap but trying to understand the difference between Spans and columns,

example

```
<div class="span4">...</div>
or 
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
```

What's the difference between them or do they do same thing?

Comment: span4 is in old bootstrap, col-md-4 in new

Answer (score 49):

```
<div class="span4">...</div>
```

is old Bootstrap syntax up until [version 2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) ,

```
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
```

is Bootstrap [version 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) syntax.

The main difference is that the new bootstrap is build on "mobile first" approach, while the old one used the typical 960gs approach to construct the grid and than had the responsivness handled separately.

You now have 4 different values that will scale the element differently based on screen size and wanted behaviour:

```
.col-md-*
```

is the equivalent of `span*`, while:

```
.col-xs-* 
.col-sm-* 
.col-lg-*
```

are used to solve the vertical stacking of elements on smaller devices (enabling you to achieve three column layouts on small screen devices by default, without having to overwrite bootstrap default classes with your own).

Comment: Also, the new grid comes in 4 sizes: http://bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide#migration

Comment: @Skelly - that is one handy link that covers all of it.

Answer (score 1):

Spans were used in BS 2 - [Scaffolding](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html)

Cols are used in BS 3 - [CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

They are, for all intents and purposes, the same thing.