# Bootstrap 2 (span) Vs Bootstrap 3 (col-md)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use to work on an asp.net mvc web application using Bootstrap v2.0, where i use the following to divide the screen into 3 parts 4x4x4 :-

```
<div class="box span4">
...
</div>
<div class="box span4">
...
</div>
<div class="box span4">
...
</div>
```

while on bootstrap v3.0 seems i need to do the following :-

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="box col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="box col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="box col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

so i have these 2 questions regarding the above:-

- is using `span` on bootstrap v2.0 have the same effect as using `col-md` on bootstrap v3.0 ?
- on bootstrap v3.0 what does `col-md-4` exactly do ??.. does it mean that the div will occupy 4 columns on large & Medium sized screens, while it will move down on small and extra small screens ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the difference between Bootstrap Spans & Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630884/whats-the-difference-between-bootstrap-spans-columns)

Comment: I think you answered your own questions.

Comment: not 100% on the difference between 2.0 and 3.0. But you are right col-md-4 means 4 columns on medium screens and up, 12 columns below medium screens

Comment: @matthewelsom, I think there is a little mistake. col-md-4 means 3 columns on medium and up, and single column (100%) on bellow screen size.

Comment: @matthewelsom but why col-md-4 will ocuupy 3 columns ,, it will ocuupy 4 columns out of 12 columns ... is this correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the different is in there break point. ***span*** breaks the layout at 767px where ***col-md-*** breaks the structure at 991px.

***col-md-4*** means a div will occupy 3 column on large and medium screen, and will adopt 100% bellow 992px.

Comment: i think you mean will ocupy 4 columns not 3 columns ?